# divide 120 students into 12 groups for 6 workshops without repeating

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have 120 students, and I'll give them 6 workshops. For each workshop, I'll divide the body of 120 students into 12 groups (so, 10 students per group).

The problem is that if some students A and B were together in group $X$ in workshop $n$, I don't want them to be together in any other workshops.

In other words, each student should meet different students for each workshop.

Is there an algorithm to solve this problem?

Note: I have given each student an ID from 1-120.

Comment: I can provide an algorithm for the case of $N$ groups of $N$ students to be partitioned in $N+1$ workshops with no repeats. If this is a practical problem , you may be able to use this as a starting point.

Comment: okay if it's possible i want that algorithm , i'm sure it will help me much , thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an algorithm for $N$ groups consisting of $N$ students each which can generate partitions for $N+1$ workshops. I'm pretty sure that this will work provided than $N$ is a prime number, which is not bad for your case because $N=11$ gives you something quite close to what you are looking for.

organize the $N^2$ students by associating each one with an element of an $N\times N$ matrix $M$ . It will be convenient to have the indices start at $0$ instead of $1$ , so the element $M_{4,7}$ refers to the $8^{th}$ student in the  $5^{th}$ group.

Use the matrix $M$ to identify the students and to populate your first workshop.

You can populate your second workshop by forming the transpose of $M$ . name this matrix $D^{(0)}$

$$ D^{(0)}_{i,j} = M_{j,i}$$

Now generate the next workshop by keeping the $j=0$ ranked students in the same group numbers they were in but shifting the group numbers of the the rest of the students by $j$ units .You need to use modular arithmetic when you do the shifting.

so

$$ D^{(1)}_{i,j} = D^{(0)}_{p,j}  = M_{j,p}$$
where $p=(i+j) \mod N$

generate the next workshop by performing the shifts again

$$ D^{(k+1)}_{i,j} = D^{(k)}_{p,j}  $$
where $p=(i+j) \mod N$

So the general formula for the $k^{th}$ workshop is

$$ D^{(k)}_{i,j} = M_{j,p}$$
where $p=(i+j*k) \mod N$

If $N$ is prime, this should generate non-repeating groups for $N+1$ workshops, $M$ in addition to $ D^{(k)}$ where $k$ ranges from $0$ to $N-1$.

Comment: yeaaaa it worked , i coded a C program that do that and it worked [ i'm so happy ^_^ ] . thanks for your time and effort .

Answer (score 2):

This problem is in the domain of the [Social Golfer Problem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/) or [Social Golfer Problem](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html).  There isn't a set algorithm for solving these.

Comment: yea that's what i'm talking about ,, but still can't find any algorithm to solve it