# Best way of forming n groups from a team of N people minimising overlap

Tags: python, combinatorics

I was recently asked the following seemingly simple question: 
What is the best way to partition a team of 12 people into groups of three, where the process is to be repeated 6 times? The solution should minimize the number of times two people are put together in the same team. 
The total number of combinations is given by,

```
nCr = 12!/(3! * (12-3)!) = 220
```

so finding a solution by hand is not really a practical proposition.
The most practical (and simplistic) solution that I found was to shuffle the 12 names and select the groups from the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th triples. Then run the process 6 times.
This did solve the problem, but there were too many situations where two people were put together in the same group, after consecutive runs.
A general solution (groups of n from N) would be nice.

Comment: This question belongs in Math, not here.

Comment: I have now posted this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It should note be in Stack Overflow either.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a variant of the "Social Golfer Problem", which is an open problem in ***graph theory***. Many thanks to [Dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792244/dave2e) who provided a clue to its solution by the [Link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435341/divide-120-students-into-12-groups-for-6-workshops-without-repeating/1435777#1435777). This link leads to two more excellent discussions of the problem at [Link2](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/) and [Link3](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html).